# Storing variables when windows app is closed and accessing them later

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Is there any way by which I can store some values in any variables and access them when windows app is started next time.

I tried storing values in text file and later accessing them but due to some file access issue I need to store these values in some kind of variable.

Comment: You can use the concept of [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: isn't that why the registry was invented?

Answer (score 0):

You can store simple types in local or roaming app settings:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer mySettings= Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings; // or RoamingSettings
mySettings.Values["myString"] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

And then retrieve them when needed:

```
string myString = mySettings.Values["myString"];
```

For more complicated types you'll need to save in a file in your application data areas: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder or .RoamingFolder

See the [App data storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#app_settings) documentation for more details.